# How to use plain background color on mobile when using Gatsby-background-image

Tags: javascript, css, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I'm using gatsby-background-image to blur-up a full screen image on my website. On the mobile version the background image is barely visible so to speed it up I would prefer just a background color there. Hiding the  component in CSS and then changing the visibility for desktop does not work as then all children are also hidden. I found about Art Direction but I'm not sure if I should use it as I am not setting multiple background images. If someone can help me I would be grateful :)

**backgroundsection.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from 'gatsby';
import BackgroundImage from 'gatsby-background-image';

const FullBackground = ({ children }) => {
  const { desktop } = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
        desktop: file(relativePath: { eq: "background-wide.jpg" }) {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(quality: 100, maxWidth: 3310) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `);
    
  return (
    <BackgroundImage
      Tag="section"
      fluid={desktop.childImageSharp.fluid}
      title="Fullscreen Background"
      id="fullscreenbg"
      role="img"
      aria-label="Fullscreen Background"
      preserveStackingContext={true}
      style={{

        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        backgroundPosition: 'center center',
        backgroundAttachment: 'fixed',
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </BackgroundImage>
  );
};

export default FullBackground;
```

Comment: I know that's not the question..... but, did you think about another (more simple) way to blur the image, either CSS or PS, something like that? I don't know, it seems to me that it would be ++ easy to manage after wards. Just my 2 cents .

Comment: @LaurentC I'm not adding blur to the image for design purposes. It's a big file and to make the loading speed of the website faster the image first loads as a blur and then sharpens. So it's only an effect im using during image loading :)

Comment: OK, so it's some kind of lazy loading method actually ?

Comment: @LaurentC I only know lazy loading as images that load when you scroll to that part of the page (image comes in the viewport). Is there any benefit from lazyloading a background image that is always in sight?

Comment: Absolutely. I have done a website on which there is a page filled with embedded YT videos which are of course very heavy to load. So while it loads, I display a low-res screenshot of the embedded videos et voilè. You can see here the results : http://danslamarge.ca/videos.php

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [Art Direction](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-background-image/#how-to-use-with-art-direction-support) to not have a background on mobile, where I set the default source as empty:

```
  const { desktop } = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
        desktop: file(relativePath: { eq: "background-wide.jpg" }) {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(quality: 100, maxWidth: 3310) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `);
  
  const sources = [
    {aspectRatio: 1, src: '', srcSet: ''},
    {...desktop.childImageSharp.fluid, media: `(min-width: 640px)`},
  ]
    
  return (
    <BackgroundImage
      Tag="section"
      backgroundColor="#000" 
      fluid={sources}
      ...
    >
      {children}
    </BackgroundImage>
  );
```